# Ruby—Nice way to chain lots of OR statements? (checking against array out-of-bounds)

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

I am doing a coding puzzle where you are a miner in an array, and you can't be out of bounds. I have this code:

```
if x > minemap.length-1 or x < 0 or y > minemap[0].length-1 or y < 0
  return false
end
```

Is there a nicer/cleaner/one-thing-per-line way to chain lots of OR statements?

Comment: `[x > minemap.length-1, x < 0, y > minemap[0].length-1, y < 0].all?` This may not be the best or the most idiomatic way, but worth a try.

Comment: @Santhosh , That's a nice approach, but it does create a temporary object (an array), allocates memory for it and than waits for the GC to collect it... these things might not matter, but it's good to keep them in mind when performance might effected (i.e., within a loop).

Comment: @Myst While it's nice that you keep pointing this out, you should also not forget Donald Knuth's famous quote: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: @MichaelKohl - I would assume such `if` statements often occur within a loop (i.e., checking the state of the board). This might not be as small of an optimization as one might imagine.... Besides, many developers claim Ruby is slow and I think it's important that we realize that sometimes our "idiomatic" approach is actually a performance hog. People don't think about the temporary objects as often as they should.

Comment: Sure, but as you said yourself you're just assuming. Besides the generational GC introduced in Ruby 2.1 and improved in 2.2 is actually built around the assumption that most objects are short lived. Hence "minor" GC runs very fast, since it only runs on the "young" generation of objects (i.e. objects that have not yet survived 3 GC runs). So while I do not deny that your point has merits, I still prefer to write idiomatic code first.

Comment: The title suggests the question is about "chaining 'or' statements", perhaps generally, but the body suggests it's about improving a specific code fragment, which happens to include several `or` operators. The question could be improved, imo, by purging it of all references to "chaining 'or' statements". Just ask how the code could be improved.

Comment: @CarySwoveland initially it was a "generic question, but to solve a specific task". However, people have answered both the generic question and how to solve the specific task well, too. I think if I needed to chain ORs or check against bounds, this page would help me in either case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, use of `or` and `and` over `||` and `&&` in conditions is not idiomatic in Ruby since they have different precedence and may not always do what you want ([Style Guide reference](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-and-or-or)).
As for the actual question, something like this is more idiomatic Ruby:

```
(0...minemap.length).cover?(x) && (0...minemap[0].length).cover?(y)
```

This uses [Range#cover?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) to check that `x` and `y` are inside the correct ranges and returns `false` unless that is true.

Comment: Is the unless block required? The condition returns boolean value

Comment: It should be `return false`

Comment: @Stefan ROFL, the best comment here so far :)

Comment: @mudasobwa no, you got me wrong :-) The OP's code contains a `return false` – it's probably a check within a larger method.

Comment: To avoid any confusion I reduced my code to the conditional which OP can use whichever way he likes.

Comment: I meant for the question to be more generic, to chain any OR statements. However, this is a beautiful way to check against ranges (which is what I was doing), so ✓ to you!

Comment: @Mirror318, I think you mean ✅, not a measly ✓.

Comment: I don't know if he wants to use `if !` or `unless`. I don't know if he wants to add a `in_bounds?` method/function with the above code and then a negated `out_of_bounds?` method/function. OP does know however, so I trust them to use the provided code any way they see fit.

Comment: I see what you mean. I was just looking at the logical expression, not noticing that `true` implies `false`. I deleted my comments. Good answer, btw; I upvoted earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the or-equals assignment operator, `||=`, to put each condition on a new line:

```
is_true = false # initial condition
is_true ||= x > minemap.length-1
is_true ||= x < 0
is_true ||= y > minemap[0].length-1
is_true ||= y < 0

is_true # will be true or false
```

In addition to the other answers, you don't need to explicitly return a value of true or false as this is implicitly done via the evaluation of the expression:

```
# will return true or false
def out_of_bounds?
  x > minemap.length-1 || x < 0 || y > minemap[0].length-1 || y < 0
end
```

You can also create a corresponding method that is just the negation:

```
def in_bounds?
  !out_of_bounds?
end
```

Comment: Definitely makes it easier to see/understand each condition... I always find that it looks cleaner too... and the whole thing (and individual parts) can be extracted to individual methods

Answer (score 2):

Although I support @MichaelKohl's answer, it does create temporary objects since two range objects are allocated to the memory for each `if` statement and their `#cover` instance method is called.

These objects live in the memory waiting for the GC (garbage collector) do work it's magic and both their existence and their use waste resources and CPU cycles.

This might not be an issue, but it could degrade performance and it might become an issue when used within a loop or if the `if` statement is called often.

On the other hand...

**IF** you know that your array never contains `nil` (i.e., if the array contains valid `true` / `false` or other numeric values, you could simply use:

```
unless x < 0 || y < 0 || minemap[x].nil? || minemap[x][y].nil?
   # ...
end
```

Or **IF** you know both x and y are always 0 or positive, use math...

```
if (minemap.length - x) > 0 && (minemap[x].length - y) > 0
   # ...
end
```

Or use math with the added conditions...

```
if x >=0 && y>= 0 && (minemap.length - x) > 0 && (minemap[x].length - y) > 0
   # ...
end
```

Good luck.

Comment: They are not identical ranges. `minemap` seems to be a 2-dimensial array, so the `y` check uses `minemap[0].length]`.

Comment: Then you also remove the `(identical)` bit in your first sentence. :)

Comment: The problem is `minemap[-1]` does a backwards index thing, instead of being `nil`

Comment: @Mirror318 - Nice catch! I removed the it.

Comment: @Mirror318 - reverse indexing can be avoided easily by the `x < 0` check (added)... but I think that an `x < 0` might be an illegal value that could be checked for earlier and could be used to raise an exception. The value should only appear when an error occurs or an attack against the app is performed.

Answer (score 2):

I'll often take advantage of `any?` and `all?` and get a little more idiomatic:

```
class Something

  def the_question?
    [ thing_1, thing_2, thing_3 ].any?
  end

protected

  def thing_1
    # …
  end

  def thing_2
    # …
  end

  def thing_3
    # …
  end
end
```

In your particular case, you're running into issues because your individual statements are a mess: they're calling a `[]` method on a local var, then calling a method on it. In other words, this context/method is probably dealing with details of objects it should be interacting with through an interface (not implementation details).

Comment: Good for more intense conditionals (but overboard for what I'm doing though)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the map has fixed size, I'd store the map's width and height in a variable or constant before creating it:

```
HEIGHT = 5
WIDTH = 10
@minemap = Array.new(WIDTH) { Array.new(HEIGHT) }
```

Then, I'd use [`between?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F) to check if `x` and `y` are within the bounds:

```
return unless x.between?(0, WIDTH-1) && y.between?(0, HEIGHT-1)
# do something with minemap[x][y]
```

BTW, it's often easier to use a hash with coordinate keys instead of a nested array, so you can use: `minemap[x, y]` instead of `minemap[x][y]`.

Answer (score 1):

The most generic solution for N ranges and N respective points:

```
ranges = [0...minemap.length, 0...minemap[0].length]
values = [x, y]
ranges.zip(values).map { |e| e.reduce(&:cover?) }.all?
#⇒ true
```

One also might explicitly query for the first not fit:

```
ranges.zip(values).detect { |e| !e.reduce(&:cover?) }
```

All not fit:

```
ranges.zip(values).reject { |e| e.reduce(&:cover?) }
```

etc.

Comment: does it have to be constants?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev let me check the documentation… Well, it looks like no, those could be local variables or even methods, returning arrays.